# How to pass dynamic data to template when createDialog used

Tags: angularjs

my UI has two buttons one for Create and another for Edit.

- Create -should show empty fields pop-up
- Edit - Existed data should be prepopulate to pop-up
- I used same pop-up for create and Edit actions

  ```
  create_quick_link.html
  <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-4">
           <font class="pull-right">Name</font>
            <span class="red pull-right">*</span>
        </label>
        <input placeholder="Name" type="text" ng-model="quickLink.name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label col-sm-4">
           <font class="pull-right">URL</font>
           <span class="red pull-right">*</span>
         </label>
         <input placeholder="URL" type="text"  ng-model="quickLink.url">
      </div>
   </div>


  $scope.editQuickLink = function (editableQuickLinkdata) {

          $scope.quickLink.name = editableQuickLinkdata.quickLinkName;
          $scope.quickLink.url = editableQuickLinkdata.quickLinkUrl;
          createDialog({
              templateUrl: '/app/ajs/followup/app/views/create_quick_link.html',
              title: 'Edit Quick Link',
              controller: 'FollowupssettingsCtrl',
              footerTemplate: '<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updateQuickLink(quickLink)">Update</button>'
          });

      }
  ```

I want to set the 
    **editableQuickLinkdata** to **quickLink**

My data is not populated .am i doing wrong ?

Comment: I got the answer here ...https://github.com/Fundoo-Solutions/angularjs-modal-service/issues/27#issuecomment-46806451

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
$scope.editQuickLink = function (editableQuickLinkdata) {
    createDialog({
        templateUrl: '/app/ajs/followup/app/views/create_quick_link.html',
        title: 'Edit Quick Link',
        controller: 'EditCtrl',
        footerTemplate: '<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updateQuickLink(quickLink)">Update</button>'
    },{myOldData: editableQuickLinkdata});

}
```

Then in the EditCtrl, in addition to $scope, you will get myOldData as an argument :

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('EditCtrl', ['$scope', 'myOldData',
function($scope, myOldData) {
 // Do stuff 
}]);
```